# PHP headers already sent error, Replace header with <meta http> tag as a solution

Tags: php

Good Day. I am hoping to get a bit of help with the following code which does the following:

- user  makes a selection
- When submit is clicked isset() is triggered, selection is recorded
- If balance is insuficient redirect to a deposit page
- Else process selection and upload to db

Now the error is received under the following condition

- The user has a zero balance and should get redirected to deposit.php

My code is:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if($_SESSION['FBID']){ //Facebook session
        $balance = getBal($userId);
    if($balance < 50){
        header("location:deposit.php"); 
        }
    else{   
    $winner = $_POST['picks'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];

    echo $winner, $score;

    $sql="INSERT INTO picks(member_nr,event_id,pick,score)
            VALUES('$uid','$id','$winner','$score')";
            mysql_query($sql)or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

            echo'<div id="dispPicks">';
            echo'<h3 style="color:red">YOUR PICKS HAVE BEEN SUBMITTED</h3>';
            echo'<h5 style="color:blue">You will be Redirected to Homepage in 3 Seconds</h5>';
            echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php" />';
            echo'</div>';

    }
```

The error says the following:

*Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by*

I am thinking of just replacing `header("location.php")`
with

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=deposit.php" />
```

but I am worried that not all users will get redirected doing this?

If anyone can offer a bit of help or advise it will be greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: @Daan NO it is NOT a duplicate, it is completely different!

Comment: This isn't so much a solution as a *workaround*. And a `http-equiv=Location` would be more dependable. Get rid of the `/>` meta tag terminator as well. As additional *fallback* use a `<script>` redirect, and a user-friendly message + link. -- And that's already the whole repertoire of *workarounds* (which is what you're asking for).

Comment: I think you have sended a content like a whitespace before. Example: `<?php # you can send your headers here ?>HTML CONTENT (or only a whitespace)<?php # you cant send your headers here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just about all you can do with a header.

Add an exit under the header()

```
if($balance < 50){
    header("location:deposit.php"); 
    exit;
    }
```

You cannot first echo a message before the HTTP header is sent.
Anything echoed is page content, content, no matter what kind, must have a HTTP header to indicate to the Browser what type of HTTP response it just received.

Once a header is sent, you are stuck with it.

I prefer this method, mostly because it is much faster.  It does not require the Browser to do another round trip HTTP Request.

```
if($balance < 50){
  include('/home/user/public_html/deposit.php');
  exit;
}
```

Personally I get annoyed at the message "You will be Redirected in X seconds"

I'd set $popWinner = true  and include the home.php, The values of $winner and $score would still be valid when in home.php.

```
else{   
$winner = $_POST['picks'];
$score = $_POST['score'];

$popWinner = true;


$sql="INSERT INTO picks(member_nr,event_id,pick,score)
        VALUES('$uid','$id','$winner','$score')";
        mysql_query($sql)or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

        $popWinner = false;  // or some other value


   include(/home/user/public_html/home.php');

}
```

Comment: your answer is well understood, thank you very much!